# Массивы в C#

Tags: c#

Помогите решить задачу.

Дано два массива одинаковой длины (по 10 элементов). Создайте третий массив, который будет отображать сумму первых двух массивов. Первый элемент третьего массива равен сумме первых элементов двух первых массивов и так далее.

Comment: А где именно встретились трудности? (Ответ «в задаче» не катит.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все просто:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{

  a_target[i] = a_1[i] + a_2[i];

}
```